# Nesting Redis Callbacks Correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, snmp, node-redis

I am writing a node.js program that receives snmp traps and stores them in a redis hash database. I haven't been programming in Node.js very long and I don't think I fully understand how my code is executing.

I feel like some of my redis calls are finishing before others and that is why I tried nesting everything in their callback functions but I am concerned that I am not doing this the proper way.

My output looks like I am getting close to what I want to achieve but there are some random concerns that pop up such as my Generation # being 1 for the first trap I receive and then 11 or 111 the next time. All I am doing is performing the redis `client.incr` function on a integer.

To put it plain and simple I am using two hash keys to keep track of current and past traps I receive. I keep track of two numbers generation and hash number as separate integer key values and increment them as needed. These two numbers are used to create and access values in the current and past trap hashes.

Here is my code.

```
function alarmCheck (key, field, value, alarmType, ipAddress) {
var historyKey = "History:"+key;
//var generationNumber;
//var numberInHash;

client.get(ipAddress+":"+field+":Gen", function (err, rep) {
    //generationNumber = rep;
    var generationNumber = rep;
    console.log("The Gen: "+rep);
    client.get(ipAddress+":"+field+":Field", function (err, reply) {

        var numberInHash = reply;
        //numberInHash = reply;
        console.log("The Field: "+reply);

        console.log("ALARM TYPE: "+alarmType);
        if(alarmType == 1) //Alarm Start value is 1
        {
            fullCurrKey = "Current:" + key;
            fullField = field + ":" + generationNumber + ":" + numberInHash;
            console.log("The FULL Field: "+fullField);
            client.hsetnx(fullCurrKey, fullField, value, function (err, status) {
                if(status == 1)
                {
                    console.log("ADDED to Current!");
                    client.incr(ipAddress+":"+field+":Field", redis.print);
                }
            })
    } else //If Alarm Start value is 0 or 2 
        {
            fullCurrKey = "Current:" + key;
            fullHistKey = "History:" + key;
            console.log("Loop generationNumber: "+generationNumber);
            console.log("Loop numberInHash: "+numberInHash);
            loop1:
            for(var i=1;i<=generationNumber;i++)
            {
                loop2:
                for(var j=1;j<=numberInHash;j++)
                {
                    fullField = field + ":" + i + ":" + j;
                    console.log("Alarm 0 or 2 fullField: "+fullField);
                    client.hget(fullCurrKey, fullField, function (err, reply) {
                        var theField = fullField;
                        if(reply == null)
                        {
                            console.log("Null hget!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Adding to history!");
                            console.log("The loop hget reply: "+reply);
                            console.log("The loop hget fullField: "+fullField);
                            console.log("The loop hget theField: "+theField);
                            client.hset(fullHistKey, theField, reply, redis.print);
                            //break loop1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            client.set(ipAddress+":"+field+":Field", 1, function (err, reply) {
                client.incr(ipAddress+":"+field+":Gen", function (err, reply) {
                    client.hset(fullHistKey, field+":"+generationNumber+":"+(numberInHash+1), value, function (err, reply) {
                        if (err)
                        {
                            console.log("Fail :( "+err);
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            });
                    }
    });
});
}
```

Here is some of my output for the current.

```
1) "Composite Gamut Error:1:1"
2) "Composite Gamut Error( -c ) 1345493146"
3) "Luma Gamut Error:1:1"
4) "Luma Gamut Error( -l ) 1345493146"
5) "Jitter1 Level:1:1"
6) "Jitter1 Level 1345493146"
7) "RGB Gamut Error:1:1"
8) "RGB Gamut Error( Rr-gBb ) 1345493146"
9) "Composite Gamut Error:1:2"
10) "Composite Gamut Error( Cc ) 1345493147"
11) "Luma Gamut Error:1:2"
12) "Luma Gamut Error( Ll ) 1345493147"
13) "RGB Gamut Error:1:2"
14) "RGB Gamut Error( R--gBb ) 1345493147"
15) "SDI Input Signal Lock:1:1"
16) "SDI Input Signal Lock( Unlocked ) 1345493147"
17) "Y Anc Checksum Error:3:1"
18) "Y Anc Checksum Error( Error ) 1345493147"
19) "SDI Input Signal Lock:2:1"
20) "SDI Input Signal Lock( Unlocked ) 1345493147"
21) "Line Length Error:4:1"
22) "Line Length Error( Error ) 1345493147"
23) "SAV Place Error:4:1"
24) "SAV Place Error( Error ) 1345493147"
25) "AP CRC Error:3:1"
26) "AP CRC Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
27) "FF CRC Error:3:1"
28) "FF CRC Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
29) "EDH Error:3:1"
30) "EDH Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
```

Here is some of my history output.

```
1) "Line Length Error:1:11"
2) "Line Length Error( Error ) 1345493147"
3) "EAV Place Error:1:11"
4) "EAV Place Error( Error ) 1345493147"
5) "SAV Place Error:1:11"
6) "SAV Place Error( Error ) 1345493147"
7) "Composite Gamut Error:1:3"
8) "Composite Gamut Error( Cc ) 1345493147"
9) "Composite Gamut Error:1:31"
10) "Composite Gamut Error 1345493147"
11) "Luma Gamut Error:1:3"
12) "Luma Gamut Error( Ll ) 1345493147"
13) "Luma Gamut Error:1:31"
14) "Luma Gamut Error 1345493147"
15) "Y Anc Checksum Error:1:11"
16) "Y Anc Checksum Error( Error ) 1345493147"
17) "RGB Gamut Error:1:3"
18) "RGB Gamut Error( R--gBb ) 1345493147"
19) "RGB Gamut Error:1:31"
20) "RGB Gamut Error 1345493147"
21) "Y Anc Checksum Error:2:11"
22) "Y Anc Checksum Error( Error ) 1345493147"
23) "Line Length Error:2:11"
24) "Line Length Error( Error ) 1345493147"
25) "Field Length Error:1:11"
26) "Field Length Error( Error ) 1345493147"
27) "SAV Place Error:2:11"
28) "SAV Place Error( Error ) 1345493147"
29) "AP CRC Error:1:11"
30) "AP CRC Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
31) "FF CRC Error:1:11"
32) "FF CRC Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
33) "EDH Error:1:11"
34) "EDH Error( Invalid ) 1345493147"
```

Comment: Hi @RoyValentine! Can you clarify your question or concern? Its unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan Sorry about being unclear. I was just dumping all about my program and didn't think about how well I conveyed my problems. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend the [async waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) for this. It will bring more structure and control to your code and reduces nested callbacks.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    redis.get('abc', function(error, result) {
      callback(error, result);
    });
  },
  function(firstResult, callback){
    redis.set('abc', firstResult, function(error, result) {
      callback(error, result);
    });
  }
], function (err, result) {
   // do something to finish operations
});
```